# Creat directory on BlobStore inGAE

Tags: google-app-engine, directory, blobstore

I want to create directory(folders)on BlobStore in GAE containing multi files ,Does GAE support that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You might be able to fake it if you use Google Storage as the object name supports '/' in it, but in BlobStore it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The blobstore stores blobs, not files. Blobs don't have paths, and they don't have filenames as identifiers. [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/) supports directories (after a fashion) - that might be a better choice.